# Help with Lishu character recognition (Character identified: 幾)

Tags: character-identification

I am practicing some Lishu characters from Deng Shiru's "Master Cheng's Admonition on Seeing, Hearing, Words, and Deeds". There is one character I'm having trouble deciphering and can't find what might be it in the Lishu dictionary I have.

[image]

The prior character is:

[image]

The following character is:

[image]

This part of the total calligraphy seems to be focused on the "Acting" of the man of wisdom or goodwill.

I'm grateful for any help in deciphering the one character.

Craig

Here is the context of the complete scroll, the fourth of four:
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to scan and post the context?

Comment: Definitely 哲人知幾，誠之於思 from [近思錄](https://zh.m.wikisource.org/zh-hant/%E8%BF%91%E6%80%9D%E9%8C%84/%E5%8D%B705) from Song Dynasty. As mentioned in another comment, somewhat surprising that 鄧石如 used a rendition of 幾 that is said of as 吴让之's in modern database. The style (the strokes, the serif etc) is consistent in the passage though. Otherwise, the characters are definite matches.

Answer (score 4):

It seems 幾

The full quote being:

> 哲人知幾，誠之於思

The preceding and following characters also match.

Reference: http://shufa.guoxuedashi.com/5E7E/3500.html

[image]

Comment: I Googled 幾 书法 鄧石如. And got http://shufa.guoxuedashi.com/5E7E/230310.html as the first return. Although in it, 鄧石如 seems to have a distinctly different style. Instead, 金农 writes a style similar to the image in the question. It will help if @CTurner scans and posts the context.

Comment: @Argyll you need to search by the correct style which in the OP is 隶书 http://shufa.guoxuedashi.com/5E7E/4/

Comment: Yes. 鄧石如 is a 隶书 calligrapher. 吴让之's version does seem identical and closer than 金农's, thanks for the link.

Comment: I have added the requested context, Argyll. Thanks to you and blackgreen for the help and advice.

Comment: @CTurner you can also accept the answer if you deem it satisfactory :)

Comment: This is fine. Yes, I do accept the answers, and thank you. I see the "Concise Dictionary of Clerical Script" which I have is not sufficient. Can you recommend a good clerical script dictionary I should look for?

Comment: @CTurner unfortunately I don't have a good recommendation for you. You might want to open a new question for that (please make sure it's on-topic first) :)