# English translation of Su Shi's "Cold Food Observance"

Tags: translation

I have obtained a copy of Su Shi's "Cold Food Observance". I would like to find a good English translation of the 129 characters, preferably with standard (kaishu) characters alongside so that I can check it to the cursive characters of the original. I have not been able to find anything online, even trying Su Dongpo in search terms. Can someone offer a direction to find this? Thanks very much.

Comment: Can't it just be found here: https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E5%AF%92%E9%A3%9F%E5%B8%96?

Comment: The characters, yes, thanks. But there is no English translation.

Comment: Don't add comments as answers, and please *accept* answers (click the tick below the answer's vote count) that you found helpful, like in your other question (https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/40798/help-with-lishu-character-recognition-character-identified-%e5%b9%be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three translations for you to muse over.

[Miao Guang](http://fgsihb.org/dictionary-info.asp?id=13550)'s translation:

> Ever since my arrival in Huangzhou,
> Three Cold-Food Festivals* have come and gone;
> Despite my intention to cherish each Spring,
> Yet the passing Spring allows no such dream.
> This year, there is once again bitter rain,
> Two months of miserable autumn-like days;
> Smelling the scents of crab-apple flowers in bed,
> By muddy soil the blushing snow is stained.
> Being stolen out in the dark,
> Obviously it was midnight's strong men;
> What difference is from an ill young man,
> Upon recovery, the hairs have already gone grey.
> The spring river about to flood my place,
> With the drenching rain not ready to cease;
> My small hut is like a fishing boat,
> Amid the fog and water it is afloat.
> In the empty kitchen I cook cold vegetables,
> Burning damp reeds beneath a broken stove;
> How was I to know it was Cold-Food Festival Day?
> From the paper-money ravens collect.
> The emperor's gate is nine-layers deep,
> While tombs are ten-thousand miles away;
> I would cry over having come upon the road's end,
> But, like dead ashes, my heart'll never kindle again.

[Bor-hua Wang](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.890.4068&rep=rep1&type=pdf)'s translation:

> Since coming to Huangzhou,
> Three Cold-Food Festivals have come and gone.
> Each year I wish to linger with spring,
> But spring admits no delay for departure.
> This year, I again suffer from bitter rain,
> Two months of autumn-like dreary weather.
> Lying in bed, I smell the crab-apple blossoms;
> Mud smudges their rouge and snow.
> In darkness, they were carried off;
> Truly, there must be a strong man [stealing them away]
> in the middle of the night.
> How does it differ from a sickly youth,
> upon leaving his sickbed, finding his hair already
> Spring flood is coming up to my door,
> But the rain shows no sign of letting up.
> My small hut is like a fishing boat,
> Blurred in misty water and clouds.
> Prepared in my empty kitchen are only cold vegetables,
> The cracked stove has only burnt wet reeds.
> How did I know it is the Cold-Food festival?
> I see scraps of paper money picked up by crows.
> The sovereign’s gates are far above nine levels [of
> Heaven];
> Tombs [of my ancestors] are ten-thousand miles away.
> I would weep [for my misery] at the end of the road,
> Only [my heart] is like dead ashes that cannot be
> rekindled.74

[Patrick Siu](https://patricksiu.org/hanshi-festival-%E5%AF%92%E9%A3%9F%E7%AF%80-and-han-shi-tie-%E5%AF%92%E9%A3%9F%E5%B8%96-by-su-shi-%E8%98%87%E8%BB%BE/)'s translation:

> Ever since I came to Huangzhou, three Hanshi (Cold Food Festivals) have passed by.
> Each year I wish the springtime can be prolonged but Spring departs without lingering.
> This year again we suffer the rain, two months of dreary, autumn like weather.
> Lying in bed, I listen to rains falling heavily on the crabapple blossoms.
> The fallen red petals and white petals are splattered in the mud.
> Spring is stolen as if by a strong figure in the middle of the night,
> It’s no different from a sick young man who rising from his sickbed found his hair has turned white.
> The spring river wants to flood the house. The force of the rain is unrelenting.
> My small house is like a fishing boat in the midst of fog and water.
> In an empty kitchen I boil cold vegetables in a broken stove burning damp reeds.
> How could I know that today is the Hanshi Festival, except that I see crows carrying ghost money from graveyards?
> The emperor’s gates are nine layers deep; the family tombs ten thousand miles away.
> Will I in the manner of Juan Chi (阮籍) weeping that the road is at an end?
> Dead ashes, blown, will not rekindle. (Feelings of despair and abandonment.)

Comment: @CTuner For your needs I would recommend Bor-hua Wang's translation to you. There's a PDF that I linked above. If you go to page 57 (pdf page: 67) of the dissertation and there is side by side English and Chinese of the poem. I think that's what you were originally looking for.